# percent_rank() in BigQuery with conditional to include only certain rows

Tags: google-bigquery

I previously posted [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58794322/bigquery-apply-rank-percent-rank-to-column-with-a-where-clause). The solution to this question works for the analytic function `rank()`, however it does not work for `percent_rank()` in the correct manner. To demonstrate, I have the following dummy table:

```
with 
  table as (
    select 'a' as category, 1 as num, 15 as num2, 7 as cutoff union all 
    select 'a' as category, 2 as num, 15 as num2, 7 as cutoff union all
    select 'a' as category, 3 as num, 5 as num2, 7 as cutoff union all
    select 'a' as category, 4 as num, 5 as num2, 7 as cutoff union all
    select 'a' as category, 5 as num, 5 as num2, 7 as cutoff union all
    select 'a' as category, 6 as num, 5 as num2, 7 as cutoff union all
    select 'a' as category, 7 as num, 5 as num2, 7 as cutoff union all
    select 'a' as category, 8 as num, 5 as num2, 7 as cutoff union all
    select 'a' as category, 9 as num, 5 as num2, 7 as cutoff union all
    select 'a' as category, 10 as num, 15 as num2, 7 as cutoff union all
    select 'a' as category, 11 as num, 15 as num2, 7 as cutoff union all
    select 'a' as category, 12 as num, 15 as num2, 7 as cutoff union all
    select 'a' as category, 13 as num, 15 as num2, 7 as cutoff union all
    select 'a' as category, 14 as num, 15 as num2, 7 as cutoff union all
    select 'a' as category, 15 as num, 15 as num2, 7 as cutoff union all
    select 'a' as category, 16 as num, 15 as num2, 7 as cutoff union all
    select 'a' as category, 17 as num, 5 as num2, 7 as cutoff union all
    select 'a' as category, 18 as num, 15 as num2, 7 as cutoff union all
    select 'a' as category, 19 as num, 15 as num2, 7 as cutoff union all
    select 'a' as category, 20 as num, 5 as num2, 7 as cutoff union all
    select 'a' as category, 21 as num, 5 as num2, 7 as cutoff 
  )
```

`percent_rank()`'s are needed for the `num` column. However, only rows where `num2 > cutoff` should be considered for the percentile rankings. I have attempted the following 2 ways to compute percentiles, with the output:

```
select
  *,
  if(num2 >= cutoff,
      percent_rank() over(
        partition by category
        order by num
      ), null) as pctile1,
  if(num2 >= cutoff,
      percent_rank() over(
        partition by category
        order by if (num2 >= cutoff, num, null) ASC
      ), null) as pctile2
from table
order by num asc
```

[image]

Both `pctile1` and `pctile2` are incorrect. To show why this is the case, look at row 10, which has `pctile1 == 0.45` and `pctile2 == 0.60`. However, amongst **qualifying values**, this should be a lower percentile. There are only 2 **qualifying** values lower than `num == 10` (that being 1 and 2), whereas there are many values above 10 that qualify (11 - 19). The correct percentile for `num == 10`, given the `num2` and `cutoff` values, should be closer to 30%, since `10` is the 3rd lowest value amongst the 11 qualifying values.

Note that I **should not** filter table to remove the rows I am not `percent_rank()`'ing over, as I need to keep these rows.

### Edit

I am not sure how to shrink image size but I am trying to do that currently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just simply go with below option

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *,
  PERCENT_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY category ORDER BY num) AS pctile
FROM table WHERE num2 >= cutoff
UNION ALL
SELECT *, NULL
FROM table WHERE num2 < cutoff
-- ORDER BY num
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - output is

```
Row category    num num2    cutoff  pctile  
1   a           1   15      7       0.0     
2   a           2   15      7       0.1     
3   a           3   5       7       null    
4   a           4   5       7       null    
5   a           5   5       7       null    
6   a           6   5       7       null    
7   a           7   5       7       null    
8   a           8   5       7       null    
9   a           9   5       7       null    
10  a           10  15      7       0.2     
11  a           11  15      7       0.3     
12  a           12  15      7       0.4     
13  a           13  15      7       0.5     
14  a           14  15      7       0.6     
15  a           15  15      7       0.7     
16  a           16  15      7       0.8     
17  a           17  5       7       null    
18  a           18  15      7       0.9     
19  a           19  15      7       1.0     
20  a           20  5       7       null    
21  a           21  5       7       null
```

In my mind above is easy to read, but below is most likely want you wanted

```
SELECT *,
  IF(num2 >= cutoff, 
    PERCENT_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY IF(num2 >= cutoff, category, NULL) ORDER BY num), 
    NULL) AS pctile
FROM table
-- ORDER BY num
```

obviously, with the same result as above

Comment: ahh, I had the `if` condition in the `order by` instead of the `partition`. Thanks for 
sharing / correcting.